# Scroll Bar should go to bottoop m whenever a new item is entered in the window at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a control like chat control in my project & the scroll bar should be set to bottom whenever a new message is entered at the bottom. Right now, the message is getting added but the position of scroll bar remains same. I have tried all solns given on StackOverflow like 
set ScrollTop to 9999999. cannot set it to the width of the container, because it is getting increased dynamically.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use html prop scrollHeight and set the container scrollTop for it:

```
insertMessage = function(message) {
  $('#chat ul').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
  var height = document.getElementById('chat-dialog').scrollHeight;
  $('#chat').scrollTop(height);
};
```